# Optamizing BVH Ray tracing to work from ray origin inside the mesh

Tags: c++, graphics, mesh, raytracing

I am working on a personal project that requires getting intersection points with a triangulated where the ray origin always has to be from within the mesh. I am currently using https://github.com/madmann91/bvh/tree/master library for this. The method bellow performs the ray intersection test with a BVH, is there any way to optimize this to account for my use case. Or are there better libraries or algorithms to consider?

```
    template <typename Node>
template <bool IsAnyHit, bool IsRobust, typename Stack, typename LeafFn, typename InnerFn>
void Bvh<Node>::intersect(Ray<Scalar, Node::dimension>& ray, Index start, Stack& stack, LeafFn&& leaf_fn, InnerFn&& inner_fn) const {
    auto inv_dir = ray.get_inv_dir();
    auto inv_org = -inv_dir * ray.org;
    auto inv_dir_pad = Ray<Scalar, Node::dimension>::pad_inv_dir(inv_dir);
    auto octant = ray.get_octant();

    auto intersect_node = [&](const Node& node) {
        return IsRobust
            ? node.intersect_robust(ray, inv_dir, inv_dir_pad, octant)
            : node.intersect_fast(ray, inv_dir, inv_org, octant);
    };

    stack.push(start);
restart:
    while (!stack.is_empty()) {
        auto top = stack.pop();
        while (top.prim_count == 0) {
            auto& left = nodes[top.first_id];
            auto& right = nodes[top.first_id + 1];

            inner_fn(left, right);

            auto intr_left = intersect_node(left);
            auto intr_right = intersect_node(right);

            bool hit_left = intr_left.first <= intr_left.second;
            bool hit_right = intr_right.first <= intr_right.second;

            if (hit_left) {
                auto near = left.index;
                if (hit_right) {
                    auto far = right.index;
                    if (!IsAnyHit && intr_left.first > intr_right.first)
                        std::swap(near, far);
                    stack.push(far);
                }
                top = near;
            }
            else if (hit_right)
                top = right.index;
            else [[unlikely]]
                goto restart;
        }

        [[maybe_unused]] auto was_hit = leaf_fn(top.first_id, top.first_id + top.prim_count);
        if constexpr (IsAnyHit) {
            if (was_hit) return;
        }
    }
}
```